# ASP.Net Core 6 - Authorize Roles not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-authorization

I have read through countless tutorials, articles and questions.

I cannot figure out why `[Authorize(Roles = "SuperAdmin")]` or any other role is not working.  Everyone gets 403 regardless of the role specified:

```cs
//[Authorize(Roles = "SuperAdmin")] - Commented out to debug roles
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var userID = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userID);
    var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

    return View();
}
```

When I debug the user, I can see that they have the role:
[image]

But they still get a 403 on any controller that authorizes roles.

Here are the relevant bits of my program.cs:

```cs
builder.Services.AddIdentity<TMSUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<MyUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>()
    .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
    .AddTokenProvider<DataProtectorTokenProvider<TMSUser>>(TokenOptions.DefaultProvider);

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Home/HandleError/401");
    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Portal");
});

builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program));
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
});

builder.Services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ITools, Tools>();

builder.Services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/HandleError/{0}");
app.UseHsts();

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

    var context = services.GetRequiredService<TMSContext>();
    context.Database.EnsureCreated();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

I have changed my code countless times over the last few months trying to get this to work, but now I'm just begging for help.  This is very frustrating!  What have I missed?  Could something else in my code be preventing this from working properly?

Thank you!

Comment: Have checked the casing of superadmin role name? Think the casing has to be equal

Comment: Yes, the casing matches.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you still have the issue?

Comment: @thanzeel The casing already matched.  That was not the issue.

Comment: Hi @flashsplat, How do you register the user and add the role to user? By using default Identity code it should work fine without custom any authorization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came up with a solution for this.  It should not have been this complicated!  I've used roles in other versions .net without this problem.

I created a custom Authorize Filter and I'm just hitting the db (which I assume all the helpers do as well so not really a big deal):

Part of this I got from [this link](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2022/02/18/net-6-role-based-authorization-tutorial-with-example-api#authorize-attribute-cs)

---

First, I created a model with my roles:

```cs
public enum Role
{
    User, Admin, SuperAdmin
}
```

Then a custom Authorize Filter:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class AuthorizeAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly IList<Role> _roles;

    public AuthorizeAttribute(params Role[] roles)
    {
        _roles = roles ?? new Role[] { };
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        // Skip authorization if action is decorated with [AllowAnonymous] attribute
        var allowAnonymous = context.ActionDescriptor.EndpointMetadata
            .OfType<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any();

        if (allowAnonymous)
            return;

        // Authorization
        var user = context.HttpContext.User;

        if (user != null && _roles.Any())
        {
            using (var db = context.HttpContext.RequestServices
                .GetService<ApplicationDbContext>())
            {
                var userRoles = (from ur in db.UserRoles
                                 join r in db.Roles on ur.RoleId equals r.Id
                                 join u in db.Users on ur.UserId equals u.Id
                                 where u.UserName == user.Identity.Name
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     r.Name
                                 }).ToList();

                var isAuthorized = false;
                foreach (var role in userRoles)
                {
                    Role claimRole;
                    Enum.TryParse(role.Name, out claimRole);
                    if (_roles.Contains(claimRole))
                        isAuthorized = true;
                }

                if (isAuthorized)
                    return;
            }
        }

        context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
    }
}
```

And I use it like this:

```cs
[Authorize(Role.SuperAdmin)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

I do like this approach.  Its going to allow me to do some other things I wanted to do on a per controller/user level - I just can't believe it was this complicated!

Hope this helps somebody.  If there's any glaring issues with this, please let me know.  I'm officially balled.

Comment: You dont need a custom authorization at all. Tjeres something wrong you are doing here, please provide a minimal repo

Comment: @Codingwiz can't mark my own as answer for 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

check what you are getting with `User.FindAll(ClaimTypes.Role).ToList()`

after that check "SuperAdmin" coming in list or not?, if your issue not resolved than post your `GetRolesAsync` function.

Comment: `var userClaims = User.FindAll(ClaimTypes.Role).ToList();` returns 0 count.  Sooo.. why wouldn't it be in there?  Why is that different from `_userManager.GetRolesAsync` ?

Comment: check your Authentication code, are you setting Role claim while login user?

Comment: I am not.  I would have thought the role was enough?  Seems redundant.  Let me research how to do that a bit...

Comment: What is your recommended method for getting SuperAdmin to appear in the ClaimTypes.Role list?

Answer (score 0):

its seems like you have to add the   `services.AddDefaultIdentity<TMSUser>()`

so the complete code would look like

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ICMSDbContext>()
                .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<CustomClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
```

Comment: I already have something similar in my code, though I do not use "Default".  I added `.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()` but it did not resolve.

Comment: Instead of AddIdentity you have to use AddDefaultIdentity, and most probably it should work

Answer (score 0):

The solution is much simpler than described. If you add both roles by .AddRoles() and custom claims by .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory(); you have to inherit from UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser, TRole> not UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser> which is a default one.

So your code should look:

```
public class CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory: UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>
  {
    public CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, IOptions<IdentityOptions> options) : base(userManager, roleManager, options)
     {
     }
  //and below should be part with adding custom claim(s)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked after enabling the session.

```
builder.Services.AddSession();
app.UseSession();
```